# Error to connect to angular docker container

Tags: angularjs, angular, docker, angularjs-directive, docker-compose

hi friends please i need help im trying to build an application angular using docker but the problem when i try to access to container don't let me i appricaite your help

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if is your case,
but solely this issue is related to Alpine vs Slim in the Docker image.

So to solve I think you can try with:

`docker exec -it your_container_name sh`

let me know if this fix your problem.

Have a nice day

### EXTENDED:

mon-project-angular_web_1 is the name of your image not the container name.

to open a shell to image you need to use:

`docker run mon-project-angular_web_1 sh`

now your inside the image and you can go with your shell.

on the other side `docker exec`, works with container; so to connect to your container you should go with:

`docker exec -it container_name/container_id sh`

container hold your image so the syntax for each ones is a little bit different.

to give a name to your container you need to go in your docker-compose and under services you need to add:

`container_name: your_awesome_container_name`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you so much bro but still the same Error :    
this my cmd  : docker exec -it mon-project-angular_web_1 sh
this the Error : No such container: mon-project-angular_web_1

Comment: sorry my fail, the right command should be: `docker exec -it id_of_container sh`, give a try and let me know

Comment: yes yes yes thank you so much bro its connected                                                        just please if you could explain me whats the diff between the 2 cmd that i used and he one you gave me